# usbmon (wireshark, tshark) for regular user

Tags: wireshark

I have libpcap set up with the newest cvs version.
Regular users can run Wireshark and tshark. 
Specifically, they have been added to the wireshark group and can capture from

```
1. eth0
2. br0
3. nflog (Linux netfilter log (NFLOG) interface)
4. nfqueue (Linux netfilter queue (NFQUEUE) interface)
5. any (Pseudo-device that captures on all interfaces)
6. lo
```

Unfortunately, they don't see the usbmon devices that root does:

```
1. eth0
2. br0
3. nflog (Linux netfilter log (NFLOG) interface)
4. nfqueue (Linux netfilter queue (NFQUEUE) interface)
5. usbmon1 (USB bus number 1)
6. usbmon2 (USB bus number 2)
7. usbmon3 (USB bus number 3)
8. usbmon4 (USB bus number 4)
9. usbmon5 (USB bus number 5)
10. usbmon6 (USB bus number 6)
11. usbmon7 (USB bus number 7)
12. any (Pseudo-device that captures on all interfaces)
13. lo
```

As root, `tshark -D` lists all the usbmon devices. However, the regular user cannot see the usbmon devices with either wireshark or tshark.

How can I make the usbmon devices availaible to wireshark group users?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://www.wireshark.org/lists/wireshark-users/201008/msg00255.html).

To enable wireshark users (those added to the wireshark group) to capture USB data, permissions for usbmon have to be changed:

```
chmod o=rw /dev/usbmon*
```

Another answer for almost the same question (with an alternative answer) is [here](https://superuser.com/questions/452910/wireshark-accessing-usb-bus-interfaces-without-sudo?rq=1).

Answer (score 7):

I solved this by creating a group for the users which should be able to use usbmon and then let udev change the ownership of the device. So just create a group, add your user to the group and place a udev rule into "/etc/udev/rules.d":

```
addgroup usbmon
gpasswd -a $USER usbmon
echo 'SUBSYSTEM=="usbmon", GROUP="usbmon", MODE="640"' > /etc/udev/rules.d/99-usbmon.rules
```

And last but not least either reboot or make sure that the user actually is in the group and trigger udev or `rmmod` and `modprobe` again.

Comment: Made it a Ansible role: [udev-usbmon](https://galaxy.ansible.com/list#/roles/2758)

Comment: Thank you.  I have been looking for the udev solution for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

From [wireshark.org](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/CapturePrivileges):

> You need to run Wireshark or TShark on an account with sufficient
>   privileges to capture, or need to give the account on which you're
>   running Wireshark or TShark sufficient privileges to capture.

Comment: The account has sufficient privileges to capture - just not usbmon apparently.